# DSL design for iOS Autolayout

Tags: f#, dsl

I am building a small DSL for iOS' autolayout feature. Obviously I want to have a typesafe way to define autolayouts instead of doing VSL. I came up with the following:

```
//in reality this will be a Xamarin/iOS View
type View = 
     | View

type Constraint = 
     | Max of int
     | Min of int
     | Eq of int
     | Both of int * int

type Element =
     | Gap of Constraint
     | Part of View * Constraint

let horizontal superview : Element list = []

let max v = Max v
let min v = Min v
let eq v = Eq v
let minmax min max = Both(min, max)

let gap c es = Gap c :: es
let view v c es = Part (v, c) :: es

//transform needs to implement the real autolayouting.
//not yet done
let transform es = List.rev es

let super_view, left_view, middle_view, right_view = View, View, View, View

horizontal super_view
    |> gap (min 20)
    |> view left_view (min 20)
    |> gap (max 30)
    |> view middle_view (eq 45)
    |> gap (eq 50)
    |> view right_view (minmax 20 100)
    |> gap (max 0)
    |> transform
```

I am sort of content with the design so far; for example, it has a pretty "fluid" touch to it. However I am asking myself if there are better ways to do it.

One particular issue is the simple fact that every definition is a intersection of "gaps" and "views" starting with a "gap" and ending with a "gap". Is there a possibility to "encode" such a design into types instead of doing it via runtime exceptions (which I would do now).

Comment: I have rephrased my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783736/how-to-create-a-typesafe-dsl-for-interleaved-function-calls